# Laravel 5.4, How to seperate \resources?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have successfully seperate the \app folder. Now it's
\app\Admin
\app\Front
\app\Models
\app\Common

I would like to do the samething to \resources
\resources\Admin\assets\
\resources\Admin\lang\
\resources\Admin\views\
\resources\Front\assets\
\resources\Front\lang\
\resources\Front\views\

How to do this?

Comment: That's going to be substantially harder, I suspect. Is `admin/assets` really so much more organized than `assets/admin` as to be worth messing with how Laravel's core finds the files?

Comment: try to see some template package which offer that

Comment: If I'm developing admin, I will use views, langs, assets. I think it's easier if they are under one admin folder. Otherwise, I have to click views > admin > somefile, lang > admin > somefile, more clicks.

Comment: But you're going to have to do just as much `admin > views > somefile`, `admin > lang > somefile`? And you'll have spent hours getting Laravel to look in non-standard places for everything that will confuse a second developer who might wind up working on your code?